# Reading an array structure with open62541 OPCUA

Tags: opc-ua, open62541

I am trying to read my `Omron NX102 PLC OPCUA Server`. I have a Data Structure
in the PLC with fields as `STRING` and an `DOUBLE`  `array of length 4`.

I can read all the information correctly from UA Expert and my code as well.

```
typedef struct {
    UA_String describe;
    size_t arSize;
    UA_Double* arguments;
} dArgument;

static UA_DataTypeMember dArgument_members[2] = {
            {
        UA_TYPENAME("describe") /* .memberName */
        & UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_STRING],            /* .memberType */
        0,                                     /* .padding */
        false,                                 /* .isArray */
        false                                  /* .isOptional */
    },
    {
        UA_TYPENAME("arguments")            /* .memberName */
        & UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_DOUBLE],             /* .memberType */
        0,                                     /* .padding */
        true,                                  /* .isArray */
        false                                  /* .isOptional */
    }
};

static const UA_DataType dArgumentType = {
    UA_TYPENAME("dArgument")              /* .typeName */
    {4, UA_NODEIDTYPE_NUMERIC, {5001}},     /* .typeId */
    {4, UA_NODEIDTYPE_NUMERIC, {5002}}, /* .binaryEncodingId, the numeric
                            identifier used on the wire (the
                            namespaceindex is from .typeId) */
    sizeof(dArgument),                   /* .memSize */
    UA_DATATYPEKIND_STRUCTURE,              /* .typeKind */
    false,                                  /* .pointerFree */
    false,                                  /* .overlayable (depends on endianness and
                                the absence of padding) */
    2,                                      /* .membersSize */
    dArgument_members
};
```

And printing the information from the `main()` as:

```
UA_ReadRequest request;
UA_ReadRequest_init(&request);
UA_ReadValueId ids[3];

UA_ReadValueId_init(&ids[0]);
ids[0].attributeId = UA_ATTRIBUTEID_VALUE;
ids[0].nodeId = UA_NODEID_STRING(4, (char*)"moveAbsoluteArgument");

request.nodesToRead = ids;
request.nodesToReadSize = 1;
UA_DataValue reading[3];

UA_ReadResponse response = UA_Client_Service_read(client, request);
reading[0] = *response.results;

dArgument* arg = (dArgument*)reading[0].value.data;
for (int i = 0; i < arg->arSize; i++)
    printf(" args[%d]: %f Describe: %.*s\n\n\n\n\n\n", i, arg->arguments[i], 
    arg>describe.data, arg->describe.data);
```

The moment I change the Type of `describe` from `UA_String` to `UA_UInt16`, it does not populate the `arSize` and I can not read the `extension object`. Somehow `UA_UInt16` is messing up my `Extension Object`. The Structure is as below:

[image]

UAExpert can read the data correctly as shown below but not the code I am trying (below).

[image]

Could someone please help with what I am doing wrong?

The code I am trying is:

```
typedef struct {
    UA_UInt16 describe;
    size_t arSize;
    UA_Double* arguments;
} dArgument;

static UA_DataTypeMember dArgument_members[2] = {
            {
        UA_TYPENAME("describe") /* .memberName */
        & UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_UINT16],            /* .memberType */
        0,                                     /* .padding */
        false,                                 /* .isArray */
        false                                  /* .isOptional */
    },
    {
        UA_TYPENAME("arguments")            /* .memberName */
        & UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_DOUBLE],             /* .memberType */
        0,                                     /* .padding */
        true,                                  /* .isArray */
        false                                  /* .isOptional */
    }
};

static const UA_DataType dArgumentType = {
    UA_TYPENAME("dArgument")              /* .typeName */
    {4, UA_NODEIDTYPE_NUMERIC, {5001}},     /* .typeId */
    {4, UA_NODEIDTYPE_NUMERIC, {5002}}, /* .binaryEncodingId, the numeric
                            identifier used on the wire (the
                            namespaceindex is from .typeId) */
    sizeof(dArgument),                   /* .memSize */
    UA_DATATYPEKIND_STRUCTURE,              /* .typeKind */
    false,                                  /* .pointerFree */
    false,                                  /* .overlayable (depends on endianness and
                                the absence of padding) */
    2,                                      /* .membersSize */
    dArgument_members
};
```

And the `main()`

```
UA_ReadRequest request;
UA_ReadRequest_init(&request);
UA_ReadValueId ids[3];


UA_ReadValueId_init(&ids[0]);
ids[0].attributeId = UA_ATTRIBUTEID_VALUE;
ids[0].nodeId = UA_NODEID_STRING(4, (char*)"moveAbsoluteArgument");

// set here the nodes you want to read
request.nodesToRead = ids;
request.nodesToReadSize = 1;
UA_DataValue reading[3];

UA_ReadResponse response = UA_Client_Service_read(client, request);
reading[0] = *response.results;




dArgument* arg = (dArgument*)reading[0].value.data;
for (int i = 0; i < arg->arSize; i++)
    printf(" args[%d]: %f Describe: %d\n\n\n\n\n\n", i, arg->arguments[i], arg->describe);
```